# How to stop toggling of checkbox for corresponding label on strongly typed views

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a bool property "retry" and created a strongly typed view but my problem is whenever I click on the label

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsReTry, new { @class = "control-label col-md-5"})
@Html.CheckBox("ISretry",Model.IsReTry)
```

the checkbox is toggling 
I don't want this to happen 
I know we can use just `@Html.CheckBox` but is there anyway we can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and not getting checked or unchecked when we click on the corresponding label

Comment: That does not make sense!  Do you have custom css styles which is placing the label on top of the checkbox ?

Comment: Note that the reason labels work that way is for accessibility. Clicking on the tiny checkbox is difficult for people with poor motor ability, whereas clicking on the label or the checkbox is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LabelFor` helper produces `label` tag that will be linked with particular input by `name` attribute (it's default browser behavior there is no easy way to change that).

Just use `DisplayNameFor` like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsReTry)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsReTry)
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oHPljf).

If you need your custom styles just wrap it with `div` or `span`:

```
<div class="control-label col-md-5">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsReTry)</div>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsReTry)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys But I think have found a simpler solution(using Jquery) for this how about we just create a class name `donoToggle` and use `e.preventDefault` on the label.